# Closed form of a finite sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

In general, has $\sum_{k=a}^{b} \binom{n}{k}$ a closed form (with $0\le a\le b\le n$)?

Comment: No,  no, no, and no (I had to type at least 15 characters).

Comment: You can read this text if your interested in this theory : https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.pdf

Comment: @zhoraster - "(I had to type at least 15 characters)" is already more than 15 characters :)